# Placing Divs side by side, with equal column heights, inside ContentPlaceHolder in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, html, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to have three columns. The left and right columns contain a button and these buttons should stay on a fixed alignment to the outside border of the container. The center column contains an `asp:Table` that is created dynamically and have everything from 1 row and 1 column to 6 rows and 7 columns.

I've tried to follow [this CSS example](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail) which ultimately becomes this site: http://www.alistapart.com/d/holygrail/example_3.html, and I've gotten the `div`s to be side by side - but I can't get the left and right columns to align vertically or have equal heights with the center div tag, which I'm guessing is the same thing.

I don't know if it matters but my divs are inside a `ContentPlaceHolder` in an ASP `Page`.

**Here's my code:**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    //Container to the three columns
    <div id="calendarContainer"> 

        //The left button container
        <div id="navigateButtonLeft" class="calendarColumn">
            <asp:Button ID="btnLeftMonth" runat="server" Text="<" 
                        onclick="btnLeftMonth_Click" /> 
        </div>

        //The table/month-calendar container
        <div id="calendar"class="calendarColumn">
            <asp:Table ID="TableMonthCalendar" runat="server" GridLines="Both" />
        </div>

        //The right button container
        <div class="calendarColumn">
            <asp:Button ID="btnRightMonth" runat="server" Text=">" 
                        onclick="btnRightMonth_Click" />  
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**and my CSS (probably worthless):**

```
#calendarContainer {
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#calendarContainer .calendarColumn {
  padding-bottom: 1001em;
  margin-bottom: -1000em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
}
#navigateButtonLeft {

}
#calendar {
  width: 80%;
}
#navigateButtonRight {

}
```

I previously used a `table` with a `tr` and three `td`s, but I couldn't get it to be the way I wanted.

Here's an illustration of what I want to achieve, which is probably better than my explanation:
[image: design goal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to format the calendar and does columns with absolute position to place then where you pretend and avoid having layout breaks further on when adding additional contents:

Please see this [Fiddle example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/vHjwr/)

Read more about this type of solution:

[CSS Position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)  |  [CSS-Tricks - Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

**Notes:**

On the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/vHjwr/), check out the **css** part to see whats being done **to positioning the elements** to a proper place. Also, the use of top and bottom allow the elements to go from top to bottom of their wrapper, in your case the wrapper is `#calendarContainer`.

---

**EDITED:**

Second [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/vHjwr/3/) with a main wrapper with no "coordinates".

---

**EDITED AGAIN**

Another [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/vHjwr/4/) using buttons styled as regular icons.

*Icons Used:*

[Arrow Left](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/42167/16/br_prev_icon) | [Arrow Right](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/42166/16/br_next_icon)

---

**EDITED TO ADD LAST REQUEST FROM OP WITH BUTTONS TOP TO BOTTOM**

The Fiddle [Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/vHjwr/5/)

Comment: Your example looks great, and is exactly what I want to achieve, but I can't have absolute positioning, since it's in a ContentPlaceHolder which is placed dynamically on the Page.

Comment: What is the final outputted HTML structure ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want when you say the HTML structure. Do you want the generated HTML from the page uploaded somewhere? Or the general structure of my page?

Comment: Also, the _absolutely positioned elements_ don't have nothing to do with the fact of being placed on the page _dynamically_, but you can always **wrap everything** on a div with `position:absolute;` with no coordinates, check my answer for the second [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/vHjwr/3/)!

Comment: If you open the page in the browser, it is rendered and some HTML structure is outputted to the browsers window. That is the HTML that should be analyzed to better understand and solve the issue. You can use a development tool like firebug or others to analyze that same output or copy it to present here.

Comment: The HTML Structure isn't out of order, if that's what you mean. And the positioning works perfectly with a wrapper around. All I'm missing now is that the buttons aren't aligned to the top. Should I update the code I have to the OP?

Comment: Don't really know what _buttons_ do you refer to, but **yes**, place and **EDITED:** at the end an give that extra markup to by analyzed.

Comment: I uploaded [a permanent image](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/6743/htmlstructure.png) to show how it looks now. And as you can see the buttons aren't fixed to a more central-vertical position (which should be an absolute position).

Comment: Did you add the **css** for the _buttons_ like I've used on the `img` tag presented on the [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/vHjwr/3/)?

Comment: Yes, like this:
#navigateButtonLeft input, #navigateButtonRight input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
}
As a second note, I'd actually prefer going with your symbols, if they were clickable, much like your hover-yellow-example, but I already have another discussion about that on here and it seems to be too hard to do.

Comment: Actually, I realized I hadn't updated the site, but it didn't work, it just moved the buttons a little up so they are on top of the header text.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11056/discussion-between-zuul-and-aske-bisgaard)